# How do I access the rows on the inside of a nested MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following nested query:

```
SELECT * FROM mrp_type 
 WHERE mrp_type.mrp_type_id 
   NOT IN ( 
     SELECT DISTINCT Z.mrp_type_id FROM ( 
         SELECT mrp_type.* , COUNT(*) as rooms_booked FROM mrp_type 
           WHERE bookings_mrp.date >= '2014-02-27' 
            GROUP BY mrp_type.mrp_type_id, mrp_type.num_rooms, bookings_mrp.date 
              HAVING mrp_type.num_rooms - COUNT(*) <= 0 ) as Z )
```

Now from the query you can see that the COUNT(*) is used is used as a condition but it does now show in the result set becasue it is in the nested query. How can I access Count(*) from my PHP code after the query has been run? Can I put it in a variable, or pass that column to the outer select or something?

Comment: What do you want the query to do?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply get the number of rows of the actual response and substract it to the table total number of row.

Edit :

Edit your query as follow :

```
SELECT * , (select count(*) from mrp_type) as total FROM mrp_type 
WHERE ...
```

Here you get the total number of rows of table mrp_type

Then using `mysql_num_rows` (php.net/fr/mysql_num_rows) on the result of your query, you'll get the number of lines selected.

After that you only have to do :

```
$rooms_booked = $row['total'] - mysql_num_rows($mysql_result);
```

Comment: That's what I am tyring to do but I figure out how to do it? Can you give me a code example

Answer (score 0):

Query the count as counter table and put it in the FROM clause

> SELECT 
>       mrp_type.*, counter.rooms_booked 
>   FROM 
>           mrp_type ,
>           (SELECT 
>                   mrp_type.* , COUNT(*) as rooms_booked FROM mrp_type 
>                  WHERE 
>                   bookings_mrp.date >= '2014-02-27' 
>                  GROUP BY 
>                   mrp_type.mrp_type_id, mrp_type.num_rooms, bookings_mrp.date 
>                  HAVING
>                   mrp_type.num_rooms - COUNT(*) <= 0 ) as counter
>   WHERE 
>           mrp_type.mrp_type_id NOT IN  
>                   (SELECT DISTINCT Z.mrp_type_id 
>                   FROM 
>                               (SELECT 
>                                   mrp_type.* , COUNT(*) as rooms_booked 
>                           FROM 
>                                   mrp_type 
>                               WHERE 
>                                   bookings_mrp.date >= '2014-02-27' 
>                           GROUP BY 
>                                   mrp_type.mrp_type_id, mrp_type.num_rooms, bookings_mrp.date 
>                                   HAVING 
>                                   mrp_type.num_rooms - COUNT(*) <= 0 
>                   ) as Z )
>       AND mrp_type.mrp_type_id = counter.mrp_type_id